# Adding a Wrapper Class to an External Class

Tags: apex, class, wrapper-class, inner-class

I am confused about what is happening in a small section of some code. I have a class that has a wrapper class inside it. There is an external class that calls this wrapper class `Models.add(new CheckItemsClass(...))` The part that confuses me is that the `Models.cls` does not have any reference or instance of `CheckItemsClass`. So how are we able to add a new `CheckItemsClass` to the `Models.cls`?

```
public class ChecklistController{
    public List<CheckItemClass> fillItems(Credit_review__c obj){
        Models.add(new CheckItemClass('Miscellaneous (Google Search Items)',obj.GIS_Stip_Notes_Miscellaneous_Search__c,obj.GIS_Stip_Miscellaneous_Search__c));
        return Models;
    }
    public class CheckItemClass{
        public string item {get;set;}
        public string notes {get;set;}
        public boolean flag {get;set;}
        public CheckItemClass(string i,string n,boolean f){
           this.item = i;
           this.notes = n;
           this.flag = f;
        }
    }
}

public without sharing class Models {
    public static void mdlEncinitas(List<WC_Credit_Decision__c> wcObs){...}
    public static void mdlDataV1(List<WC_Credit_Decision__c> wcObs, List<ID> wccdIds) {...}
    public static void mdlDataV2(List<WC_Credit_Decision__c> wcObs, List<ID> wccdIds) {...}
    public static void mdlEncinitasRecommender(WC_Credit_Decision__c wcOb, Integer score10pt, Integer score, String productionChannel, Double grossSalesRunRate, Double judgmentTotalAmt, Integer maxTib, Double avgOfAvgDailyBal, Double bkDateYrs, Integer maxFICO, String sicCode, NF_SIC_4__c sicOb, Credit_Review__c crOb, WC_Buy_Rate__c brOb, Boolean lenderMissing, Double maxNegDaysLst3Mnths, String oppType, List<Decision_Attribute__c> decisionAttr, Double maxNegDaysEver, Double maxNSFsEver) {...}
    public static void mdlEncinitasRun(ID wcId, WC_Credit_Decision__c wcOb, Credit_Review__c crOb, Opportunity oppOb, List<Monthly_Review__c> mrObs,NF_SIC_4__c sicOb, Account acctOb, WC_Buy_Rate__c brOb, Boolean brokerMissing, Map<Id,List<Credit_Review_Monthly_Ledger__c>> CR_ledgers_map, List<Decision_Attribute__c> decisionAttr){...}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Somewhere else in the local context, there is a variable declaration that's shadowing the class `Models`.

Example:

```
public class TestQ242685 {
    public class InnerClass {

    }

    public static void runTest() {
        List<InnerClass> SomeOtherClass = new List<InnerClass>();

        SomeOtherClass.add(new InnerClass());
        System.debug(SomeOtherClass);
    }
}

public class SomeOtherClass {
    // No `add()` method!
}
```

Call `TestQ242685.runTest()` and sure enough, you'll see

> 16:04:08:034 USER_DEBUG [10]|DEBUG|(InnerClass:[])

You've got a `List<CheckItemClass> Models` declared somewhere.

Comment: ah you are right, it was at the very top. I totally missed it. thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You seem to have a name *shadowing* here.

This code is adding `CheckItemClass` objects in a `List<CheckItemClass>` which is most likely declared in your controller as:

```
List<CheckItemClass> Models = new List<CheckItemClass>();`
```

And from [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_naming_conventions.htm):

> In particular it is legal for a variable, method, and a class within a class to have the same name.

So that's why you are not getting any compile errors with same names. It's always a good idea to keep names specific to the context.

And it's the same variable that's being used in your `fillItems()` method as below:

```
public List<CheckItemClass> fillItems(Credit_review__c obj){
    Models.add(new CheckItemClass('Miscellaneous (Google Search Items)',obj.GIS_Stip_Notes_Miscellaneous_Search__c,obj.GIS_Stip_Miscellaneous_Search__c));
    return Models;
}
```

So `Models.add()` is not really calling any method in the `Models` class, but the [`List.add()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_list.htm) method. Also refer to the return statement which confirms as what you are returning.

Comment: thank you! I realized I missed the `List<CheckItemClass> Models = new List<CheckItemClass>();`. This is a good example of how important naming is. It can get easily confusing!

Answer (score 3):

Name shadowing can take many forms...

Here is my personal favorite (as I have made this mistake more than once wrto name shadowing) from the lazy loading pattern...

```
public Contact[] contacts {
  get {
    if (contacts == null) {
       Contact[] contacts = [SELECT ... FROM Contact WHERE ...]; //oops - declared new vbl!
    }
    return contacts;
  } private set;
}

if (contacts.isEmpty()) {...} . // null pointer exception!
```